# Docker volume permissions broke after copying

Tags: permissions, docker

I am using Docker and Docker Compose to manage my containers. For backup reasons, I previously had all my Docker files (volumes etc.) running on `/home/docker` which was symlinked via `/var/lib/docker -> /home/docker`.

After a while I decided moving my `/home/docker` directory to a different SSD using

```
$ cp -r /home/docker /my/new/ssd/docker 
$ rm /var/lib/docker 
$ ln -s /my/new/ssd/docker /var/lib/docker 
$ rm -r /home/docker
```

which I fear changed all the permissions since I can't run most of the containers anymore due to permission issues.

Example:
Azuracast throws following error:

```
{"level":"error","time":"2022-07-22T23:30:02.243","sender":"service","message":"error initializing data provider: open /var/azuracast/sftpgo/sftpgo.db: permission denied"}
```

where `/var/azuracast` is being stored on a docker volume.

I now want to restore all those permissions.

**Is there a way to restore Docker permissions for all existing volumes or to tell Docker to take care of this?**

What I tried so far:
I recursively changed all permissions to `root:root` using `chown -R root:root /my/new/ssd/docker`.

This problem is causing serious issues for my server environment and I'm aware that using `cp -r` instead of `rsync -aAX` was a huge mistake so I would greatly appreciate any help here.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Please add  the mount options of `/my/new/ssd/docker` in your question.

Comment: Tough to say, I had to completely reinstall my docker installation because I messed up some move processes, thus the problem is gone now. Thanks nevertheless for taking the time @Marco.